# How to plot with no default x-axes in J?

Tags: j

I want to plot in J with 2 list of data: data1 and data2 as y-axes and x_axes. I want to know how to define the x-axes but not use the default i.($y).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a scatter plot giving both the x-axis and y-axis coordinates as follows:

```
   load 'plot'
   ]data1=: 20 ?@$ 500
282 212 154 130 84 355 35 307 108 123 266 460 299 462 93 91 435 341 27 437
   ]data2=: 20 ?@$ 100
73 3 7 10 93 32 25 48 45 11 21 95 84 63 33 6 84 9 93 65

   plot data1;data2
```

However the default plot is a line so this may not give the result you're after. Adding some [options to the plot command](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Plot/Options) might help.

```
   'type dot;pensize 2.5' plot data1;data2
```

[image: J scatter plot]

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I plotted the 135 points but the points are too small to see. I tried to change the pensize and it didn't work.

Comment: @Anne if you provide the code that didn't work it will be easier to help.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have found the reason and solved the problem! I should let the code going in your presented order.