# Scatter plot in J

Tags: plot, j

How do you create a scatter plot in J?

I can see how to easily create a line plot.

```
load 'plot'
plot i. 10
```

I have a hunch it has something to do with the `jzplot` class and the `pd` verb, but after scouring the documentation, I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47764334/how-to-plot-with-no-default-x-axes-in-j

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my hunch was correct.

```
load 'plot'
plt_val =: 3 : 0
pd 'reset'
pd 'pensize 5;type point'
pd <y
pd 'show'
)

plt_val p: i. 10
```

You can do a scatter plot of the first 10 primes.

The `type point` is the critical piece

Answer (score 1):

Even (a bit) easier:

```
load 'plot'
'pensize 5;type point' plot p:i.10
```